# VBA Function Return SQL Value Expected Function

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database (I'm not after reasons to not use Access).

I am trying to run a VBA sub to cycle through some queries based on a parameter, which is a query result.

There's a query which sums the value in the table for a column. 
I need to return this with a function in VBA using an IF ELSE statement to proceed.

```vb
Public dbs As DAO.Database

Sub Main()

Dim SumCheck As Double
Set dbs = CurrentDb

GoTo LoopCheck

LoopCheck:
    SumCheck = SOSum(dbs)
    If SumCheck = 0 Then
        GoTo EndPart
    Else
        GoTo STPTGet
    End If
```

The code doesn't proceed past here, instead when I step into the code it stops here at this function and gives the error "Expected Function or Value"

```vb
Public Function SOSum(db As DAO.Database) As Double
    Dim sumg As Double
    Set db = dbs
    Set sumg = db.Execute("LoopCheck")
    Set db = Nothing
    Set SOSum = sum

End Function
```

The loop check query is simple

```sql
SELECT SUM(Qty)
FROM SO;
```

The query works in Access, it should just check if it's 0 or not.

This is my first post, so excuse any incorrect formatting or obviously missing information. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `Set SOSum = sum` should not have the `Set` keyword since this function returns a double, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, it looks like you have `dbs` as a public Database object. Because of this, you don't need to pass it around to your function. You can just use it once it has been set.

Next, the `db.execute` method will only run action queries (like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE...) and it doesn't return anything. You'll need to use a recordset to get at the results of your query.

Lastly, your function returns a `Double`, so you shouldn't be using the `Set` keyword to return the value.

Put all together we have this:

A Database object Global Declaration:

```
Public dbs as DAO.Database
```

A `MAIN` Sub (only partial was given in the question):

```
Sub Main()

Dim SumCheck As Double
Set dbs = CurrentDb

'...

SumCheck = SOSum

'...
```

And your SOSum Function:

```
Public Function SOSum() As Double
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs= dbs.OpenRecordset("LoopCheck")
    sum = rs(0).Value
    Set rs = nothing

    SOSum = sum

End Function
```